# ubuntu 22.04: Audio jack not working

Tags: sound, 22.04, hp, headphones

I am running ubuntu 22.04 along with windows 11 in dual boot, audio jack is properly getting recognized in windows 11 but for some reason it is not recognized in ubuntu 22.04, speakers working fine in both.

Laptop Model: HP HP Laptop 15-fd0xxx
Codec: Realtek ALC236